# Need to create an image using HTML using c# for netstandard2.0?

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

I need to use simple HTML templates to generate images in a C# console app, but it must support .netstandard 2.0

Comment: Do you mean an HTML renderer / headless browser?

Comment: @Slaks  yes without a browser

Comment: You need a headless browser.